# MySQL Export with Column Heading

Tags: mysql, export

I am very, very, new to mySQL.  I've got experience in general technical terms, but not with the syntax or concepts of mySQL.  I have been tasked with exporting a table from MySQL into a pipe delimited .txt or .xls that I can use to add 7500 more records to manually, then import back into the table.  I tried to use INTO OUTFILE, but I don't get column headings, which I need for reference to merge the new records.

Is there a good resource that can explain this to a complete novice?  I would usually go down to my bookstore and start learning, but I'm on a bit of a time crunch.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQLYog: it (even the free edition) has built in commands that make various forms of import/export easier (export to CSV format etc.):

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list